# Calculator with Decimal, Octal and Hexadecimal Numbers

Tags: c, binary, hex, octal

I want to make a calculator that is capable of calculation with decimal numbers and is able to return the decimal values in their respective binary, octal or hexadecimal representation.

So far in the main method the program reads the command line and I can invoke the program by two ways.

The first way would be with 3 values:

> "number1" "operator" "number2".

And the second way would be with 4 values:

> "wished numeral system for the output" "number1" "operator" "number2".

Where for the wished numeral system output b would stand for for binary, o for octal and h for hexadecimal. In both ways the user should be able to input decimal, octal and hexadecimal numbers for the inputs number1 and number2.

```
#include "zahlen.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stringTOint.h"   

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char o,op,sx[DIGITS+1],sy[DIGITS+1],sz[DIGITS+1];
    int x,y,z;
    char flag_x,flag_y;

    /* 1) Read Commandline */
    if (argc != 4 && argc != 5) {
        printf("Aufruf: %s -o <x> <op> <y> \n",argv[0]);
        return 1;
    } else if(argc == 4) {
        x = stringTOint(argv[1]);
        op = argv[2][0];
        y = stringTOint(argv[3]);
    } else if(argc == 5) {
        o = argv[1][0];
        x = stringTOint(argv[2]);
        op = argv[3][0];
        y = stringTOint(argv[4]);
        if(o != 'b' && o != 'o' && o != 'h') {
            printf("Wrong Operation\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    /* 2) Solve the equation */
    if(argc==4) {
        printf("solve: %s %c %s \n", argv[1], op, argv[3]);
        z = solve(x, op, y);
    } else if(argc==5) {
        printf("solve: %s %c %s \n", argv[2], op, argv[4]);
        z = solve(x, op, y);
    }

    /* 3) Calculate the Representation of the wished Numeral System */
    switch(o) {
        case 'b':
            intTObinaer(x, sx);
            intTObinaer(y, sy);
            intTObinaer(z, sz);
            break;

        case 'o':
            intTOoctal(x,sx);
            intTOoctal(y,sy);
            intTOoctal(z,sz);
            break;

        case 'h':
            intTOhexal(x,sx);
            intTOhexal(y,sy);
            intTOhexal(z,sz);
            break;

        default:
            intTObinaer(x, sx);
            intTObinaer(y, sy);
            intTObinaer(z, sz);
            break;
    }

    /* 4) Return the results */
    printf("\n  %s %d\n%c %s %d\n= %s %d\n", sx,x,op,sy,y,sz,z);

    return 0;
}
```

The methods intTObinaer, intTOoctal and intTOhexal only differ by the base with which the decimal number gets divided.

```
intTObinaer(int i, char str[]) {
    unsigned int zahl = i;
    int j;

    /* Fill Array with zeros */
    int x = 0;
    for (x; x < DIGITS+1; x++) {
        str[x] = '0';
    }

    /*Calculate the Binary representation of the given Decimal integer */
    for (j = DIGITS-1; j > 0; j--) {
        /* This base gets changed to 8 or 16 for octal and hexal representation */
        str[j] = (char) (zahl % 2) + '0';
        zahl = zahl / 2;
        if (zahl == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }

    /* Set the end of the Array */
    str[DIGITS] = '\0';
}
```

The actual equation gets solved in the solve method, where the right operation for number1 and number2 gets chosen by an switchcase where the different cases can be selected by the char op that the user had input between the two numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int solve(int x, char op, int y) {
    int ergebnis = 0;
    switch(op) {
        case '+':
            ergebnis = x + y;
            break;

        case '-':
            ergebnis = x - y;
            break;

        case '*':
            ergebnis = x * y;
            break;

        case '/':
            ergebnis = x / y;
            break;

        case '&':
            ergebnis = x & y;
            break;

        case '|':
            ergebnis = x | y;
            break;

        default:
            printf("Wrong input\n");
    }

    return ergebnis;
}
```

My question now is due to the fact the the user should be able to input different numeral systems(e.g. decimal, octal or hexadecimal) how can I identify the different numeral systems and then transfer them into decimal so that I can calculate the result. After that these decimal Numbers have to be converted back into the desired numeral system that the user wanted.

Comment: There's no way to know if a number like `3` belongs to octal, hex or decimal without any sort of indicator. You must ask the user to specify which system each input will be in.

Comment: So in my case I would go with no prefix for a decimal value, a zero as prefix for octal numbers and a 0x as prefix for hexal numbers

Comment: @Trikalium What should happen with errant number input like `0128`, `0x12abx`?

Comment: In case of something like '0x12abx' or '0128' there should be best be a warning during the stringTOint convertion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you only need to add two lines to do that:

`#include "stdlib.h"`

`#define stringTOint(arg) ((int)strtol(arg,NULL,0))`

Or better yet, replace those invocations of `stringTOint()` with corresponding `strtol()` invocations (and add the #include, of course).

`strtol()` uses the same prefixes as for C literals: `0` for octal, `0x` for hex, no prefix is decimal.

Comment: Thank you @chux , I don't know how I bungled that

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest another approach to this problem.

Many of the parsing you perform can be performed directly by the `sscanf` function, the only case is the binary case that needs to be implemented differently.

The implementation follows 3 main step:

1. Parse the input using the `sscanf` function (or the `ConvCharToBin`for binary values) and store the values in the variables `a` and `b`;
2. Perform the operation and store the result in the `res` variable;
3. Print the output result by using the `printf` parsing (or loop for the binary case).

An implementation would be the following:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct stack {
    unsigned char data[32];
    int size;
} stack_t;

int ConvCharToBin(char* input);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char numSys = 'd', op;
    char** param = argv;
    int a, b, res;

    param++;

    //error case
    if(argc != 4 && argc != 5) {
        //not a valid input
        printf("Not a valid input");
        return -1;
    }

    if(argc == 5) {
        numSys = param[0][0];
        param++;
    }

    op = param[1][0];

    switch(numSys) {
        case 'b':
            a = ConvCharToBin(param[0]);
            b = ConvCharToBin(param[2]);
            break;

        case 'd':
            sscanf(param[0], "%d", &a);
            sscanf(param[2], "%d", &b);
            break;

        case 'h':
            sscanf(param[0], "%x", &a);
            sscanf(param[2], "%x", &b);
            break;

        case 'o':
            sscanf(param[0], "%o", &a);
            sscanf(param[2], "%o", &b);
            break;

        default:
            //no viable number system
            return -1;
    }

    switch(op) {
        case '+':
            res = a + b;
            break;

        case '-':
            res = a - b;
            break;

        case '/':
            res = a / b;
            break;

        case '*':
            res = a * b;
            break;

        case '&':
            res = a & b;
            break;

        case '|':
            res = a | b;
            break;

        default:
            //no valid operand
            printf("invalid operation\n");
            return -1;
    }

    stack_t tmp;
    tmp.size = 0;
    int i;

    switch(numSys) {
            case 'b':
                while (res) {
                    if (res & 1) {
                        tmp.data[tmp.size] = '1';
                        tmp.size++;
                    } else {
                        tmp.data[tmp.size] = '0';
                        tmp.size++;
                    }
                    res >>= 1;
                }
                for(i = tmp.size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    printf("%c", tmp.data[i]);
                }
                printf("\n");
                break;

            case 'd':
                printf("%d\n", res);
                break;

            case 'h':
                printf("%x\n", res);
                break;

            case 'o':
                printf("%o\n", res);
                break;
        }

    return 0;

}

int ConvCharToBin(char* input) {
    char* idx;
    int res = 0x00000000;

    for(idx = input; idx < input + strlen(input); idx++) {
        res <<= 1;
        if(*idx == '1') {
            res |= 0x00000001;
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

The `sscanf` reads formatted data from a string (in you case the `argv` strings)

This can be parsed using the following:

- `%d` for decimal;
- `%x` for hexadecimal;
- `%o` for octal.

Unfortunately there is no C standard for parsing binary using `sscanf`, so this is done apart using the `stdout`.

I would also point out that this implementation has two limitation

- Input/output limited to 32 bit unsigned (so from `0` to `4294967295`), but with some slight modifications it can be extended;
- No error checking for the input values, this can also be easily implemented.

Comment: `for(idx = input; idx < input + strlen(input); idx++)` is quite _novel_.  How about a nice simple `for(idx = input; *idx; idx++)`?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand how the content of my pointer (`*idx`) can be used as the `for loop exit condition`. Wouldn't the loop end as soon as 0 is found in the input string?

Comment: Yes, the loop ends as soon as 0 is found in the input string.  Is not that the goal, to end the loop when the _null character_ is read?

Comment: Ah gotcha! I just forgot that the value is ASCII encoded. Cheers :)